# assigning a domain to a site on a IIS of a local network,

Tags: iis, dns, localhost

I developed a site for some company which have their own local network, and it's running on their server which is not connected to internet (only their network), the server has its own static IP and DNS server of the local network. when users want to connect to the site they type http://123.4.3.10:8088 or something like that but I want to let them connect with only typing http://MySite or maybe only Mysite (users computers is connected to internet beside the local network). is it possible? how can I do so? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through the DNS server of their local network. You can see which ones (dns server) are used in the client's network interface configuration/status.
If you don't know about it ask their DNS server administrator to set up an `A` dns record with the name `mysite` to point to `123.4.3.10`.
You can not change the port with dns!!! Default HTTP port is 80. If you're using port 8088 the new URL will be `http://MySite:8088`.